# Pythonic way of checking if variable exists and if so, comparing it to another

Tags: python-3.x

I often find myself in a situation where i need to check if i assigned something to a variable and then if so, compare it's value to something else.

Sure, I know how to do it, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way of handling this.

EXAMPLE:

```
def function():
  with suppress(SomeException):
    variable = 10

  if variable and variable > 5:
    # do things
```

That will give me an UnboundLocalError exception (in case of `SomeException` happening during variable assignment). Again, I know how to code it, so it will work, it's the style of coding that troubles me. I want to avoid creating unnecessary local variable.

Comment: what's about processing the variable inside `with` statement?

Comment: @enoted, well, yeah, i guess. But it can hurt readability.

Answer (score 1):

You say you know how to do it, but the code you posted will throw an exception if the assignment doesn't happen.

There really is a simple way to do this: just don't write code that can leave a variable uninitialised.

```
def function():
  variable = None

  if SomeCondition():
    variable = 10

  if variable is not None:
    # do things
```

Note that this doesn't create any unneeded local variables, the variable `variable` would be created whether or not you assign to it, but if you don't assign then it is uninitialised and testing whether it is initialised means having to throw and catch an exception, and that is slow. Simply initialising it means you have a simple easy test. Stop trying to optimise things that don't need optimising.

Comment: Sorry, i edited my question. I hope it's more clear now, that example i posted is not how it supposed to be done, but how i'd like it to be done. I know it wouldn't work. But maybe there is some other way?

Comment: Yes, the other way is to always initialise.